# Asus G73SW's backlit keyboard doesn't work, nor does the FN+F3- & F4 hotkeys

Tags: asus

Asus G73SW's backlit keyboard doesn't work, nor does the <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> hotkeys.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would work for your backlit keyboard. Just came across it.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1752900

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Pardon me. Being a noob to such forums, I hadn't really put much thought into it. Also, I didn't take the time to peruse the suggested answer as I wasn't looking for it in the first place.

Will take care to follow guidelines in the future.

Comment: You could edit this answer and add in the essential parts.